# IE8 vs IE8 compatibility mode inset border CSS issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a inset style on a border in CSS. It displays fine in IE 8 compatibility mode, but in IE8 is shows a black border instead of the regular inset. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

```css
#div {
  border-style: inset;

  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Hit F12 or open the developers tools.  In "compatibility" mode IE trys to render in the lowest possible settings .. which on IE8 is usually .. the dreaded IE7 .... ew.

Comment: Can't reproduce. And consider using the shorthand `border-style` instead of all `border-*-style` properties.

Comment: @Oriol   
I am using the shorthand border style. Sorry

Comment: @britter looks fine in IE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By declaring only the "style" property, the browser uses his fallbacks for width (1px) and color (black). You have to set all the border properties:

```
#div {
  border: 3px inset grey;

  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Does IE actually use those defaults instead of `medium` and `currentColor` (or whatever IE < 9's internal implementation of it would be)?

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm pretty sure, that black is the color in old IEs. But yeah, for the border-size it could be medium.